Tensorboard doesnt seem to load data from Anaconda prompt
From the Anaconda prompt I run:
tensorboard --logdir='directory'

It runs, without an error:
"Serving TensorBoard on localhost; to expose to the network, use a proxy or pass --bind_all
TensorBoard 2.10.1 at http://localhost:6006/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)"
But when I open that location Tensorboard shows: "No dashboards are active for the current data set."
Then I start jupyter notebook, open terminal there, and (from the same location) run the exact same command, and I see the data in Tensorboard.
Can someone explain this? And ideally, also how to solve this, such that I can load the data to Tensorboard directly from the Anaconda prompt. Thank you!
